How to open an HTML file with Visual Studio Code inside of a Docker container?
I'm in Visual Studio Code's terminal inside a Docker container.
How do open an HTML file in Visual Studio Code from the Bash terminal inside a Docker container?

code /path/to/html/file doesn't work?

This question is way too broad and basically asking for a learning material. There are tons of ways to do so, the most VSCode one is linked above.

Showing the research that you've done and the things you've tried so far would go a long way towards making this a better question. Please EDIT your post and add that and any other info that shows the effort you've put into solving this. These sorts of details may appear arbitrary, but they, in fact, go a long way towards focusing your question, helping us understand the nature of your environment, and telling us what not to suggest as you've already tried that.

VSCode has an extension called Visual Studio Code Dev Containers for containerized development.
Microsoft has elaborate documentation on how to make use of this and make optimal use of VSCode and Docker/Docker compatible containers. You can find this documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers
For those of us with a shorter attention span, they also have a quick and dirty tutorial providing a quick basic setup at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/tutorial

Install Docker/Docker compatible CLI.
Download or create a container for development. (https://containers.dev/
Connect to your docker (Plain folder, SSH, GIT,...)
Configure your project via devcontainer.json

For the above question, VSCode works the other way. When you have properly setup your project and connected VSCode to your container, you can open a terminal from within VSCode ! Any terminal window you open from VSCode (Terminal > New Terminal) will automaticly open inside the container.

Although after reading the documentation for Dockers in Visual Studio code. How do you get Visual Studio Code to recognize a Docker container, once you are inside a Docker Container in Visual Studio Code integrated terminal ?

I'm not sure i fully understand your question. You can attach VSCode to an already running container by selecting Dev Containers: Attach to Running Container... from the Command Palette or use the Remote Explorer in the Activity Bar and under Containers  selecht Attach to a container

It appears as though I'll have to update Windows as Dev Containers: Attach to Running Container requires Docker Desktop 4.34.3 and my build number of Windows is incompatible.
Therefore I'll have to revisit this question once this is accomplished.
